# two arrays in one form to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a form with two fieldsets which contains checkboxes:

```
<fieldset style="width:300px; height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="table[]" id="01" value='ado'> Adoption <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="table[]" id="02" value='acc'> Accomodations <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="table[]" id="03" value='ann'> Announcements <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="table[]" id="04" value="bea"> Beauty/Fitness <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="table[]" id="05" value="bus"> Business Oportunities    
</fieldset>
```

and this one

```
<fieldset style="width:300px; height:200px; overflow:scroll;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="State[]" id="01" value='AL'> Alabama <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="State[]" id="02" value='AK'> Alaska<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="State[]" id="03" value='AZ'> Arizona<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="State[]" id="04" value='AR'> Arkansas <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="State[]" id="05" value='CA'> California <br />
</fieldset>
```

Im using this code to go into their respective tables

```
$table = $_POST['table'];  
$name = $_POST['name'];
$state = $_POST['State'];

if(is_array($table)){
  while(list($tables) = each($table)){
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tableName (name,table) VALUES ('$name','$tables')";
    $q2 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql2);
    }
}           

if(is_array($state)){
  while(list($key,$value) = each($state)){
   $sql3 = "INSERT INTO states (name,State) VALUES ('$name','$value')";
   $q3 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql3);
     }
}
```

when it gets executed the only data that gets entered is states
I used

```
echo "table; ".$table."<br /> State; ".$state;
```

and got

```
table; Array
State; Array012ALAKAZ
```

someone help me!

Comment: You can't echo an array, use `var_dump($table)` and `var_dump($state)` to see what's in them.

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

And your `table` query is using a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so the entire insert query is failing. Since you failed to check for failure, and simply assumed success, you'll never see any error messages.

Never **EVER** assume success when dealing with an external resource (especially a database). There's exactly **ONE** way for a query to succeed, and a near infinite number of ways for it to fail. Yet you seem to think that 1:infinity odds are really good.

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO tableName (name,`table`) VALUES ('$name','$tables')";
                                     ^-----^---you need these

$q2 = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error($db_conx));
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---you also need this
```

Comment: Thanks I made the necessary changes and now its working

Answer (score 0):

Here you have solution what makes only 2 queries  instead of 20 and so queries:

```
$tables = $_POST['table'];  
$name = $_POST['name'];
$states = $_POST['State'];

$states_values = '';
$tables_values = '';

$i = 0;
foreach($states as $state)
{
    $i++;
    $last = $i == count($states) ? true : false;
    $states_values .= '(' . $name . ', ' . $state . ')' . ($last ? '' : ',');
}

$i = 0;
foreach($tables as $table)
{
    $i++;
    $last = $i == count($tables) ? true : false;
    $tables_values .= '(' . $name . ', ' . $table . ')' . ($last ? '' : ',');
}

mysqli_query($db_conx, 'INSERT INTO states (name, State) VALUES ' . $states_values;
mysqli_query($db_conx, 'INSERT INTO tableName (name, table) VALUES ' . $tables_values;
```

As Marc said, you should escape your inputs.